# Enable 'Title' attribute for images with TinyMCE Editor

Tags: editor, images, tinymce

When inserting an image in an article using TinyMCE editor's, the popup that appears only has options for Image Source and Alt text but no way to add a title for the image. It seems like there is a way to add this as it is disabled by default according to [TinyMCE documentation](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/plugins/image/#image_title). I tried changing the /plugins/editors/tinymce/tinymce.php file just to try it out but it does not seem to do anything different in any 'modes'. Is there any way we could enable this or is this not possible?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current version of TinyMCE (v4.4.3) now seems to have this option enabled (see below).

[image: TinyMCE Image Title]

Comment: Yes you are correct. I can see it now. Thank you for following up.

Answer (score 1):

You also can add an image in the **Image Button** at the bottom,
see the screenshot. From here you can add your image title.

[image]

Best Regards!

Comment: That button does work but only on the first instance when the image is inserted. After that, without deleting the image; it's not possible to do so with the TInyMCE editor button.

Answer (score 1):

You can consider change to JCE Editor. This component its great, free and have too many options to manipulate images. 
Included this your need for title Image. Try In:

https://www.joomlacontenteditor.net

Comment: Yep that is an alternative but unfortunately not a viable for us. That is why I was wondering if there was a way to change the instantiation parameters or manually update TinyMCE.  Looks like both are not possible at the time being.